# Secure a service account with a firewall rule

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to secure a service account (google-cloud-platform) with a firewall rule (source ip) but it does not work. Apparently the service account is not associated with the firewall rule or VPC (in the same project). How can I associate a VPC or firewall rule with a service account? Or what did i wrong.

Comment: Did you check the [GCP Firewall documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#serviceaccounts) how can you set the firewall rule ? Also If you can describe more how you try to set the rule, like make a screenshot and share it with us, so that we can help you more and have a better understanding of what causes the issue and how we can help you to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Some more detail on what you're trying to achieve would help, however service accounts are used for authenticating to Google APIs, and so cannot have firewall rules applied to them.

Comment: For security reasons, I want only a specific IP address to have access to the service account (and the Google API) for the project. I thought the firewall rule for the service account is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Craig, Service accounts are used for authentication and can't have Firewall rules applied to them.

The steps mentioned on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#serviceaccounts), is used to apply Firewall rules based on the Service account being used by GCE Instances.